# Missing fields in relationship table when using Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am using Code First with Entity Framework 6.1.2.

I have two entity / master tables like so:

```
[Table("Foos")]
public class Foo
{
  [Key]
  public string Id { get; set;}

  // More fields
  ...
}

[Table("Bars")]
public class Bar
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set;}

  // More fields
  ...
}
```

And I just defined a relationship table between them like so:

```
// Each foo can have zero or more bars.
[Tables("FooBars")]
public class FooBar
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set;}

  [ForeignKey("Foo")]
  public string FooId { get; set;}
  public Foo Foo { get; set;}

  [ForeignKey("Bar")]
  public int BarId { get; set; }
  public Bar Bar { get; set;}

  // Extra fields in this relationship table
  public bool ThisRelationshipGoingGood { get; set;}

  // More fields
  ...

}
```

And I updated the `Foos` entity definition like so:

```
[Table("Foos")]
public class Foo
{
  [Key]
  public string Id { get; set;}

  public ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }

  // More fields
  ...
}
```

But when I run the `update-database` commandlet in PowerShell / Nuget Package Console, the updated database's `FooBars` table only has the following columns:

```
FooBars
----------
FooId (string)
BarId (int)
```

It does not have the `ThisRelationshipGoingGood` field or any other fields I added to the `FooBars` entity.

How do I have the `FooBars` table have the remaining fields I defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this :

```
[Table("Foos")]
public class Foo
{
  [Key]
  public string Id { get; set;}

  [InverseProperty("Foo")]
  public ICollection<FooBar> FooBars { get; set; }

  // More fields
  ...
}

[Table("Bars")]
public class Bar
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set;}

  [InverseProperty("Bar")]
  public ICollection<FooBar> FooBars { get; set; }
  // More fields
  ...
}

[Tables("FooBars")]
public class FooBar
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set;}

  public string FooId { get; set;}

  [ForeignKey("FooId")]
  [InverseProperty("FooBars")]
  public Foo Foo { get; set;}


  public int BarId { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("BarId")]
  [InverseProperty("FooBars")]
  public Bar Bar { get; set;}

  // Extra fields in this relationship table
  public bool ThisRelationshipGoingGood { get; set;}

  // More fields
  ...

}
```

and in consol package manager , before update-database command , first add-migration , then use update-database command.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'd found the solution a couple of hours after posting the question but my schedule has been so tight I never found the time to update this thread with an answer, which would basically have been the same thing you wrote. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used add/enable-migration ?? 
look at this tutorial https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx
I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. I have migrations enabled.